# Allow UITapGestureRecognizer inside UIAnimations

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to show a custom view when I receive a notification from parse.
This view is showed with an animation and its hidden with another animation. This view also has a uitapgesturerecognizer that needs to be fired when the user taps the view.
My problem is that when the second animation gets fired the custom view's uitapgesture doesn't work :\

Any ideas? I paste the code.
Thanks!

```
func doManageObjectNotification(notification: COPushNotification){
    mainView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
    customView = CustomNotificationView()
    let height = customView.calculateViewHeight()

    customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -height, mainView.frame.width, height)
    customView.targetMethod = notificationWasTapped
    customView.setContent(notification)
    customView.alpha = 0
    mainView.addSubview(customView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
       // Show the view
        self.customView.frame.origin.y = 0
        self.customView.alpha = 1
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 5, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
            // Hide the view
            self.customView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { finished in
                self.customView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.customView = nil
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Im agree with [Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317541/1894067) answer, but I want also focus your attention about `customView.frame.origin.y = 0` during animation:  if you use **autolayout** and you try to change frame dimensions or positions instead the correct constraints involved, you can disable you constraints effect causing warnings and unexpected view dimensions and movements. When you have this issue many times the `UITapGestureRecognizer` stop to responding.

The best way to do it is to create IBOutlets constraints and working with it (for example):

```
@IBOutlet weak var customViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

...
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in
       // Show the view
        self.customViewTopConstraint.constant = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip Alessandro I will have a look at this ;)

Answer (score 1):

For handling tap during animation you should implement `touchesBegan` method. by this you can detect touch and then check that touch is from your view,if yes then you can perform your desired task.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you so much Lion for you answer. I realized that the problem is the instruction customView.alpha = 0 which tells the ui that this view is invisible so automatically all touch events are cancelled. My solution was to put customView.alpha = 0.1 and when animation finished then remove the view from the superview. After this, the gesture and touches began (as you said) both worked ;)